# A Proof for a Sequence Convergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

Here's my question to prove:

> Define $a_n$ to be a sequence such that:

$$a_1=\frac{3}{2}$$
$$a_{n+1}=3-\frac{2}{a_n}$$

> Prove that $a_n$ is convergent and calculate its limit.

**Solution**

> Prove by induction that $a_n$ is monotonic increasing:

- For $n=2$, $a_2=3-\frac{4}{3}=\frac{5}{3}>\frac{1}{2}$
- Assume that $a_n>a_{n-1}$
- For $n=k+1$: $$3-\frac{2}{a_n} - (3-\frac{2}{a_{n-1}})=-\frac{2}{a_n}+\frac{2}{a_{n-1}}>0$$, since $a_{n-1}<a_n$ which makes $\frac{2}{a_{n-1}}>\frac{2}{a_n}$
- Therefore, the sequence is monotonic increasing.

> Prove that $2$ is an upper bound of the sequence. Therefore, it is monotonic increasing and bounded, thus convergent (induction).

Now I think that $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} a_n=2$, and I want to prove it with the squeeze theorem.

Is my solution, correct?

Is there a way to  find supremum here?

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: Have you shown that $2$ is an upper bound? Assuming you have, then let $L$ be the limit.  Then $L=3-\frac 2L$.

Comment: @lulu I think I have, by induction. With your method I am just solving a quadratic equation? Why is it "legal" to do it? how do I just "decide" that 2=$L$?

Comment: If so, then you have shown that the limit $L$ exists, do you see why?  Then write $a_{n+1} = 3- \frac {2}{a_n}$ and take limits of both sides, invoking the continuity of the function $\frac 1x$.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $2$ is an upper bound of the sequence, use the fact
that $a_{n}$ is monotone increasing and $a_{1}=3/2$ so that $a_{n}\geq3/2$,
or $1/a_{n}\leq2/3$.

The limit of the sequence is a fixed point of the function
$x\mapsto3-2/x$. You can find the fixed points of this function by
solving $x=3-2/x$ (hint: quadratic formula). One of these points
will be $2$ (the other is irrelevant; can you figure out why?).

You do not need the squeeze theorem here.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a limit $x \ne 0$  then $x=3-2/x$, giving $x^2=3x-2$, giving $x=1$ or $x=2$. Since  $a_1=3/2$ and the sequence is increasing ,we have $3/2 \le a_n<3$ by induction on $ n$. Hence the limit $x$ exists  (because $3$ is an upper bound for the increasing sequence) and  $ x>a_1>1$, so  $x= 2$.